# Light or heavy carriers conduct

Tags: electric-current, conductors, charge-carrier

I want to obtain the 2D carrier density in a n-type FinFET, which depends on the effective mass but I am a bit lost between this two kind of carriers. I have to consider the (DOS) effective mass of electrons at low T and I don't know if to take the one for heavy or light electrons, any advice ?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a little? Context is needed to determine how to proceed.

Comment: I want to obtain the 2D carrier density in a n-type FinFET, which depends on the effective mass